# Page title variable, can I fetch from file also?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my main layout page, I was to have this:

```
<title> TITLE_FROM_CONFIG || @page_title </title>
```

Basically if the page_title variable wasn't set, then use the default page title.

I want to get the default page title from a config file or something, what do you suggest I use for this?

this is rails 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always add an initializer file (config/initializers/constants.rb) that contains config options for your application.  Make sure you use Ruby constants here so they're available in the top-level namespace of your application.

Comment: A quick note, nothing special about "constants.rb" -- this can be whatever you want.  Everything in config/initializers/* gets loaded automatically.

Comment: Anything that starts with a capital letter is a constant.  APP_PAGE_TITLE = "my page title"

Comment: Just remember you have to restart `rails server` to see changes to constants which are defined like this.

Answer (score 0):

I use https://github.com/markbates/configatron to store application wide settings, so I would store my default page title using that (check the docs). Then the code you have above would be like this (assuming erb):

```
<title><%= @page_title || configatron.default_page_title %></title>
```

Comment: This works as well, but I don't recommend using a gem/plugin unless you really need it.  Creating a config file as an initializer is simple -- you don't need a library for it.

Comment: I completely agree it is more simple to use an initializer, however I find myself needing different values for those constants (depending on environment or deployment) not far down the path in most development life cycles. Loading the initializer file with if statements or such is less elegant than for example using `configatron.configure_from_hash` and loading the configuration from elsewhere. Also the available dot notation is just nice on the eyes ;)